# Images Sd card android

Tags: android, image, android-sdcard, bitmapdata

My question is there any android library which does the following features

1.Accessing images from sd card as thumbnails

2.Click on thumbnail shows the actual image.On the swipe of that image it should show the other images. 
I implemented this feature using view flipper but which was costly as i need to add all images to the viewfilpper while loading.

Any links related to this will be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any dedicated library for this. But with we can achieve this by creating Gallery View and give sd card path as the path for images in the activity.